# How do I resolve ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration for NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults and declare reasons why my app uses UserDefaults?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm getting ready to distribute my first app on the iOS store. My app uses UserDefaults to save a few variables for when the app is relaunched.

I've heard I need to declare the reasons why I'm using UserDefaults, but I'm unable to figure out where I should do so. On App Store Connect, UserDefaults isn't listed under Capabilities. I assume this might be in a plist on Xcode's Build Settings, but I'm completely lost. Any suggestions?

Edit 01: This is where I heard I need to declare a reason (last paragraph): https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/storing-user-settings-with-userdefaults

Comment: Where did you hear this? It's simply not true. There's nothing to declare just for using UserDefaults.

Comment: @HangarRash, last paragraph here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/storing-user-settings-with-userdefaults, and this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api

Comment: According to the documentation you linked to, you need to include the reason in your app's privacy manifest file

Comment: @Paulw11, yes I'm aware, hence the question: where / how do I declare it? This is my first app, and not very familiar with setting plists in XCode

Comment: This appears to be a very new requirement after looking at the Apple docs you linked. None of my existing apps have ever done this before. But I haven't posted any app updates in a few months. Interesting...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Start with Apple's documentation for [Privacy manifest files](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files). You need to create a privacy manifest file.

> To add the privacy manifest to your app in Xcode, choose File > New File, and scroll down to the Resource section. Select the App Privacy file type, click Next, then click Create. By default, the file is named PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy; don’t change the filename. At the top level of this property list file, add the following keys to the dictionary.

For the UserDefaults privacy reasons, you need the key `NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes`. This is described in the above documentation as:

> An array of dictionaries that describe the API types your app or third-party SDK accesses that have been designated as APIs that require reasons to access. For information on the keys and values to use in the dictionaries, see [Describing use of required reason API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api).

The UserDefaults specific section can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api#4278401).

The following shows a minimal example for indicating that you only use app-specific values in UserDefaults:

[image]

The corresponding XML of this plist looks as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>CA92.1</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It's much easier to create this in Xcode as a plist and not as XML since Xcode lets you select only the relevant keys and values.

My example shows the UserDefaults reason as `CA92.1`. You must of course provide the value(s) appropriate for your app.

My example also only shows a bare minimum just for the UserDefaults API. See the linked documentation for other top-level keys you also need as well as other APIs your app may need to provide.

Comment: Please note that I have not actually submitted an app with this privacy manifest yet so I can't confirm this is 100% correct at this time. If anyone finds an issue with this answer, please post a comment with details so the answer can be fixed as needed.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have worked for me. I'm still getting warning emails:
"... file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults. While no action is required at this time..."

<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
   <array>
    <string>CA92.1</string>
   </array>
   <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
   <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
  </dict>
 </array>
</dict>
</plist>

Comment: @laurie It would be best to post your own question with all relevant details to ensure you get specific help.

Comment: I got the same warning email referring to user defaults but also regarding file timestamp access. While the time stamp reason numbers auto-complete (seems all of them), this is not working for some of the reasons listed under user default (at least 1C8F.1 won't auto-complete).